# Does my 1-year old need a visa to enter the UK?

Tags: visas, uk

My child will be a year old when travelling and is a holder of a South African passport.

Will she need a visa to travel to the UK for a one-week holiday?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, every visa national needs a visa regardless of their age.

You can verify that here: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/south-africa/tourism

Comment: What does "visa national" mean?

Comment: Someone who needs a visa to enter the UK even for a short trip. For example South African passport holders are visa nationals but US citizens are non visa national